# Sanity check on file encryption method

Tags: java, encryption

I'm encrypting a file as part of a greater application doing other things. The file is being encrypted with AES encryption (random key) and wrapped in RSA public key encryption. The reason for this is the encrypted file will then be sent/accessed by the appropriate person with the matching private key only.

My core function for encrypting the file is below. I write the keyBlock to the front of the encrypted file, and then the encrypted data.

I have a few questions:

1) From an architectural and security standpoint, is this method of encrypting a file a secure way to indeed encrypt a file? -- or is it a bit silly? If silly what other alternatives may be reasonable; and

2) is attaching the keyBlock to the front of the encrypted file OK from a security standpoint?

Cheers and thanks in advance for any thoughts or commentary.

Java function:

```
// File in = plain input file
// File out = encrypted output file
// Key pubKey = public Key (that wraps a random AES key)
public static void encryptFile(File in, File out, Key pubKey) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fin;
    FileOutputStream fout;
    int nread = 0;
    byte[] inbuf = new byte[1024];
    fout = new FileOutputStream(out);
    fin = new FileInputStream(in);

    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    // symmetric wrapping
    Key sKey = createKeyForAES(Config.SYM_CRYPTO_STR, random);
    IvParameterSpec sIvSpec = createCtrIvForAES(0, random);

    // encrypt symmetric key with RSA/pub key
    Cipher xCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Config.RSA_INSTANCE);
    xCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey, random);
    byte[] keyBlock = xCipher.doFinal(packKeyAndIv(sKey, sIvSpec));

    fout.write(keyBlock);
    System.out.println("keyblock size = " + keyBlock.length);

    // encrypt data with symmetric key
    Cipher sCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Config.AES_INSTANCE);
    sCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sKey, sIvSpec);


    // Now read our file and encrypt it.
    while((nread = fin.read(inbuf)) >0) {
        byte[] trimbuf = new byte[nread];
        for(int i=0;i<nread;i++)
            trimbuf[i] = inbuf[i];

        byte[] newtmp = sCipher.update(trimbuf);
        if(newtmp != null)
            fout.write(newtmp);
    }

    byte[] finalbuf = sCipher.doFinal();
    if(finalbuf !=null)
        fout.write(finalbuf);

    fout.flush();
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Now read our file and encrypt it.
while((nread = fin.read(inbuf)) >0) {
    byte[] trimbuf = new byte[nread];
    for(int i=0;i<nread;i++)
        trimbuf[i] = inbuf[i];

    byte[] newtmp = sCipher.update(trimbuf);
    if(newtmp != null)
        fout.write(newtmp);
}

byte[] finalbuf = sCipher.doFinal();
if(finalbuf !=null)
    fout.write(finalbuf);
```

You're making a mountain out of a molehill:

```
// Now read our file and encrypt it.
while((nread = fin.read(inbuf)) > 0) {
    fout.write(sCipher.update(inbuf, 0, nread)); // cannot be null, by construction
}
// NB doFinal() cannot return null, but can return a zero-length array, which is benign below.
fout.write(sCipher.doFinal());
```

> From an architectural and security standpoint, is this method of encrypting a file a secure way to indeed encrypt a file?

I believe it's quite common.

> 2) is attaching the keyBlock to the front of the encrypted file OK from a security standpoint?

It's as secure as your private key.